# Spark-submit issue - looking for non-existent path

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to run spark-submit:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/bin/spark-submit  sdp-consumer.py
```

It gives **error**:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/bin/spark-submit: line 27: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.2.0/libexec/bin/spark-class: No such file or directory
```

Why is it complaining about 2.2.0 when that does not exists?
(I do not have any ENV that points to 2.2.0)

How to use spark-submit or how to solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm, your `$SPARK_HOME` is blank? You should be able to `cat` your `spark-submit` (it's a bash script) and see that it invokes `"${SPARK_HOME}"/bin/spark-class`.

Comment: echo $SPARK_HOME  
`/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec`  So still not sure why is it going to 2.2.0.

Comment: What happens when you `source /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/bin/find-spark-home`? Does your `$SPARK_HOME` change then?